# Method from superclass cannot be overridden when return type is a List

Tags: java, inheritance

When I want to return a `ArrayList` of `C2`, it's not possible, because the return types are incompatible.

```
package a;
class C1 {
  private final ArrayList<C2> c2s = new ArrayList<C2>();

  protected ArrayList<C2> getC2() { return c2s; }
}

class C2 {}

package b;
class C1 extends a.C1 {
    private final ArrayList<C2> c2s = new ArrayList<C2>();

  @Override
  protected ArrayList<C2> getC2() { return c2s; } // won't work
}

class C2 extends a.C2 {}
```

**Update:** Why doesn't this work, when following works (in a.C1 and b.C1):

```
private final C2 c2 = new C2();

public C2 getC2() { return c2; }
```

Comment: You made it very confusing using the same simple class names in both packages. Short answer: Because a.C2 is not b.C2!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two different `C2` classes - an `ArrayList<a.C2>` isn't the same as an `ArrayList<b.C2>`. They're incompatible to avoid this sort of thing:

```
ArrayList<b.C2> listB = new ArrayList<b.C2>();
ArrayList<a.C2> listA = listB; // This is invalid...
listA.add(new a.C2());
b.C2 firstElement = listB.get(0); // To stop this from causing problems.
```

That has nothing to do with overriding, it's just normal generics. You could change your declaration in `a.C1` to:

```
protected ArrayList<? extends C2> getC2() { return c2s; }
```

*Then* it would work, because the types will be compatible. That prevents the above abuse because you can't call `add` on an `ArrayList<? extends a.C2>`.

As an aside, I would *strongly* discourage you from having class names which are only distinguished by package. It's a recipe for unreadable code and painful debugging sessions. It's also a recipe for hard-to-read questions, so if your real code doesn't use this nasty naming scheme, please don't make your sample code use it either.

Comment: Thanks, but there's still an ambiguity. Please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: @halloei: There's no ambiguity here - while you can override a method to return a more-specific type, `ArrayList<b.C2>` is *not* a more-specific type than `ArrayList<a.C2>`. They're not assignment-compatible.